# It is possible to filter the symbols by type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use `goToSymbol` command (php file for instance) it shows all symbols of the file (classes, methods, functions, variables, callbacks etc). In 99% of the cases I just want to see methods. How can I get a list of methods only?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to list *only* methods, but you can add a `:` to the filter textbox to group results by type:

[image]

If you want to have a keybinding for this, you can pass the text that should be pre-filled via the `"args"` of the `"workbench.action.quickOpen"` command ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54424758/2631715)):

```json
{
    "key": "<keybinding>",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
    "args": "@:"
}
```

Unfortunately the `:` seems to be preselected, which might be a bug considering other "special characters" like `@` and `>` are not.