# How to pre-filter showCommands in VSCode's quickOpen panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got a few extensions that add 4, 6 or more commands and I don't want to set a shortcut for each of them.
Ideally I could create a shortcut to show all commands of that extension.
Alternatively something that shows the `workbench.action.showCommands` list with some text set already in there so that just the interesting commands are shown.
Something like this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+[Backquote] z",
    "command": "workbench.action.showCommands",
    "args": { "text": "task marks" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Any ideas how to do this? I could not find `workbench.action.showCommands` in VSCode's [API documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this (with whatever keybinding you choose) :

```json
{
  "key": "alt+z",
  "command" : "workbench.action.quickOpen", 
   "args"   : ">task marks",
   "when"   : "editorTextFocus"
}
```

I got the syntax from [issues: adding an argument to the quickOpen panel](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28617).

Oddly, this will not work:

```json
"command": "workbench.action.showCommands", 
"args": "task marks",
```

Only the `workbench.action.quickOpen` command will take the argument.