# How to enter text in command palette in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension. I use the following code to enter text in the TextEditor area.

```ts
function insertText(params: string) {
  var editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
  editor.edit(edit =>
    editor.selections.forEach(selection => {
      edit.delete(selection);
      edit.insert(selection.start, params);
    })
  );
}
```

BUT, what I need my extension to be able to enter text in areas like:

- command palette
- input area when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (for `workbench.action.gotoLine` command)

instead of asking for user input.

---

tl;dr

pseudocode for what I am asking:

```ts
openCommandPallete();
enterTextInCommandPallete("ABCDEF");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `quickOpen` command with an argument to pre-fill the text:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.quickOpen", "Hello World");
```

[image]

You can switch to the command palette by prefixing the text with `>`. The full list of possible prefixes for quick open can be checked with `?`:

[image]

As you can see here, `:` is the prefix for "Go to Line", so that works with the same command:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.quickOpen", ":5");
```

[image]

There's a related question that deals with how to utilize arguments for quick open in keybindings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420051/how-to-pre-filter-showcommands-in-vscodes-quickopen-panel/54424758#54424758).

Comment: Thanks! it helped me refine the `gotoSymbol` (ctrl+shift+o) command based on category:
{
        "key": "ctrl+o",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "args": "@:",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }